# couldnot maintain the string format that is needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want my result in this format

```
data: [{"label":"present","value":35},
{"label":"absent","value":50},
{"label":"leave","value":45},
{"label":"performance","value":67}]
```

I did try this code

```
data: <%= @orders.map { |d| {label: d.shipping, value: d.price}}.to_json.html_safe -%>
```

which gives result

```
data: [{"label":"present","value":"35"},
{"label":"absent","value":"50"},
{"label":"leave","value":"45"},
{"label":"performance","value":"67"}]
```

here problem is in the first label present i  obtain  value "35" in this format but i need value 35 only without "". How could i get this?
my data in @orders is

```
    [#<Order id: 8, price: "35", purchased_at: "2012-01"
, shipping: "present", created_at: "2012-12-13 08:17:39",
 updated_at: "2012-12-13 08:50:13">, #<Order id: 9, price
: "50", purchased_at: "2012-02", shipping: "absent", created_at
: "2012-12-13 08:31:24", updated_at: "2012-12-13 08:50:55">,
 #<Order id: 12, price: "45", purchased_at: "2012-03", shipping: 
"leave", created_at: "2012-12-13 08:48:37", updated_at: "2012-12-13 08:51:07">
, #<Order id: 13, price: "67", purchased_at: "2012-04", shipping:
 "performance", created_at: "2012-12-13 08:48:47", updated_at: "2012-12-13 08:51:18">]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: <%= @orders.map { |d| {label: d.shipping, value: d.price.to_i}}.to_json.html_safe -%>
```